# InterlockedExchange fails under vmware, workaround?

Tags: c, winapi, vmware, esxi

A very simple approach. 
Two threads.

```
volatile __int32 p=0;
```

One thread (A) only use

```
while(1){
    ExecuteAVeryCPUIntesiveThing();
    InterlockedExchange(&p, 0);
}
```

The other thread (B) uses

```
while(1){
    if(0==InterlockedCompareExchange(&p,0,0))
        InterlockedExchange(&p, 1);
}
```

If one try to log this under a system under stress. (a lot of memory swap, io, socket, cpu spikes ..)
the values from A don't get propagated to B.

In A p seems to have the value of 0.
But from B's perspective p is stuck at 1.
In my world when A sets the value to 0 B should detect and set the value to 0.
And on real hw this works just like that but not when running on esxi.

This seems to work fine under real hardware and under some virtual system but not under vmware.

Have I done a mindslip or ...?

OS guest: win2008 server

code compiled with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for x64

Host: esxi 4.1

Update:

Response to comments: yes it will bounce between 0 and 1,
  but as written, thread B will not bounce, because the value from p never/or rearly changes in B's perspective, it will bounce 10-20 times and then stop.

I would like to only execute code block in A (  ExecuteAVeryCPUIntesiveThing();) at very precise moments.

The production code is full with more threads and events, mutex and locks but the fact remains, if I strip and only use the above code I can reproduce it if I generate a lot of cpu, mm, io on the guest os.

Comment: This isn't very meaningful. What are you trying to achieve, what's the bigger task?

Comment: This isn't your real code (InterlockedExchangeCompare does not exists) so we can't be sure whether or not this is really what you are doing. You've not said in what way it fails. The code is simply going to bounce 0 and 1 into `p`. In fact, the `if` statement seems pointless given that. And `while(1)`? What is the real problem?

Comment: As an aside, why use Interlocked at all here? And why use that if, it seems spurious. MSVC volatile gives you all you need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I think your not reading my question the way I intended ;). The code seems fine, does it job under real hw but fails under vmware!! It's like the two threads have their own local copy of p instead of a shared one.

Comment: No, I can read the question fine. I don't understand why you are using InterlockXXX here for no reason and I don't understand why you need an if in thread B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a threading race waiting to happen.  You probably got it from VMWare because you allocated only one processor to the virtual machine.

What the code is missing is an interlock that ensures that thread B has *seen* the value of `p` change.  So if thread A acquired a cpu core and keeps running for a while and thread B is blocked, waiting for a quantum to run then thread A can set `p` to 0 more than once.  Thread B will be oblivious of that since it never got a chance to set `p` back to 1.

You'll need to rethink your lock design.  The problem isn't limited to just VMWare, it can go wrong on a regular machine as well, just a lot less likely.  It goes wrong once a month, give or take, impossible to debug.  This is otherwise a classic producer/consumer scenario, one you address with a thread-safe queue.

Comment: ah, I think you got something. The original code could only trigger the A thing by posting a msg (from B) to a thread safe queue but in my strip down example I removed all these things. The lock things were added to prevent a thread from posting one special msg if it already was in the queue.